# What happens if too many devices connected to multiple i2c buses on ESP32?

Tags: i2c, esp32

See this diagram:

[image: multiple devices on a single bus]

In the above diagram, multiple devices are connected to a single i2c bus.

In my previous question, I was wondering what would happen if there are too many devices on a single i2c bus. In this case, ESP32 has two buses. So I was wondering what would happen as I keep adding more devices to each bus?

I figure there are three scenarios:
1. Neither bus has too much load
2. One bus is below load, the other bus has too much load
3. Both buses have too much load.

What happens to my ESP32, and the devices connected to it in each of the above three cases?

Comment: Each device adds some capacitance. So you would need to use smaller pull-up resistors. If you're not talking about devices, but about modules which every one contains pull-up resistors, you should remove those resistors.

Comment: I’m using modules like adafruit bno055, and drv2605L. To use those I normally just connect sda to sda, scl to scl etc. does that mean I don’t need to add resistors?

Comment: assume some devices dont play well with others.   you really need to use a scope to look at the bus to see that the levels are okay.  with off the shelf modules where you dont have as much control and/or may not want to modify them you may end up with fewer items possible.